# Using Mathematical Operations in /testfor command in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Say I have the objective `test` which is `stat.killEntity.Zombie`. I also have another objective `test2` which is also a `stat.entityKilledBy.Zombie`. Can I make a new objective, which is a `dummy`, and the value of that is `test + test2`. Is this possible? If not, what is the best alternative?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `/scoreboard` command allows you to perform operations with player's scores.

To make it so that `test3 = test + test2` for all online players, do something like this:

```
execute @a ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @p test3 = @p test
execute @a ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players operation @p test3 += @p test2
```

That makes everyone set their `test3` score to their `test1` score, and then add onto that their `test2` score.

This is only sets their `test3` score once (it won't automatically always be `test + test2` now), so you'll need to do this on a clock or just before you `/testfor` a certain `test3` score.

Comment: Mind blown. Wow.