# How do I do multiply scoreboard values?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I make a command that basically sets var1 = var2 * var3?

Is there a way to do this in minecraft 1.8.8?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Mathematical Operations in /testfor command in Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/233746/using-mathematical-operations-in-testfor-command-in-minecraft)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for can be done via the aptly named [`scoreboard players operation`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard) set of commands.

```
scoreboard players operation <targetName> <targetObjective> <operation> <selector> <objective>
```

This sets `<targetName>`'s score in `<targetObjective>` based on `<selector>`'s score in `<objective>`, according to the `<operation>`.

The latter can be any of += (add), -= (subtract), *= (multiply), /= (divide), %= (modulo), = (set), < (min), > (max) or >< (swap).

In order to set var1 = var2 * var3 for "target", you can run two commands:

```
scoreboard players operation <target> var1 = <target> var2
scoreboard players operation <target> var1 *= <target> var3
```

Comment: I'm on mobile atm, might expand this a little later on.

Comment: I'm using this for two fake players so do I just replace the names?

Comment: @WiiCraft I think var1 requires an actual entity,  but `selector` should work fine with fake players.